# How do you capture a click on an HTML element that has a CSS 3D transform away from the screen?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a div that rotates around the x-axis, around its center, so that the top half "falls away" from the screen while the bottom half comes toward the screen. When I try to capture the onclick event, I only get it from the div if I click on it below its centre. If I click on it above its center, the containing div receives the onclick event.

I've tried moving the div to the front with z-index and translateZ(), but still the containing div receives the onclick when I click on the top half of the div.

How can I get the div to receive the onclick event, regardless of where on the div it is clicked?

Here's a sample that demonstrates the problem:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<script type="text/javascript">
function onMainClick() {
    console.log('onMainClick()');
}

function onContainerClick() {
    console.log('onContainerClick()');
}
</script>
<title>Click Test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div onclick="onContainerClick()" style="width: 200px; height: 200px; background-color: burlywood">
        <div onclick="onMainClick()" style="width:100%; height: 100%; background-color: grey; -webkit-transform: perspective(1000px) rotateX(45deg)"></div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

onMainClick() is not called when clicking the top half of the grey div.

Comment: post a sample html so it would be easier to get your idea

Answer (score 0):

Built the case in a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3ddZx/5/), I don't exactly know what the perspective rotation does, but the solution is to give the other div a z-index of -1...

**CSS**

```
#div1 {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: burlywood;
    z-index: -1;
}

#div2 {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: grey;
    -webkit-transform: perspective(1000px) rotateX(45deg);
}
```

Update: correct jsfiddle link...

Comment: Beware 'z-index: -1;' can make some browsers not print the element. Just a note.

Comment: As long as those browsers aren't Chrome or Safari... the whole thing doesn't work on any other than webkit anyway.